# C# with Real Time Chart

Tags: c#, charts, controls

Every minute, I get a temperature from 6 sensors in my greenhouse.
I store this values in a multidimensional array.
grh1[x,0],grh1[x,1],grh1[x,2],grh1[x,3],grh1[x,4],grh1[x,5]
My quetion is: how use this array to put every minute data in the Chart Control Line and the X axis in HH:mm format like this 00:00  00:01  00:02 (this is running time, not system time).
Thank in advance, ocaccy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you store the "start date/time" somewhere to use it together with the array index X as offset? For example, if you store DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Now, before starting to read the sensor every minute, you know that x=0 means dateStart, x=1 means dateStart.AddMinutes(1),  x=2 means dateStart.AddMinutes(2), etc.

Then when binding the values you simply take the index "x" and convert it back into date time and then format it like this:

string labelX = dateStart.AddMinutes(x).ToString("HH:mm");